# use Object.create instead of setPrototypeof

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have the following code that ensures `Promise.reject` returns an actual error object:

```
export const rejectWithAnError = function(error) {
  if(error.constructor === Error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }

  const err = { error: true, message: error };
  Object.setPrototypeOf(err, new Error());
  return Promise.reject(err);
};
```

I then came across this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) that says using Object.create would be better.

How would I use `Object.create` in this scenario?

Comment: why dont use [Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error

Comment: I could use new Error but this is a learning exercise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That MDN link says in particular:

> If you care about performance you should avoid setting the `[[Prototype]]` of an object. Instead, create a new object with the desired `[[Prototype]]` using `Object.create()`.

So, instead of making an object with the literal expression `{ error: true, message: error }` and changing its prototype later, you should make a new object whose prototype is `Error.prototype` and then set properties on it:

```
const err = Object.create(Error.prototype);
err.error = true;
err.message = error;
```

On [MDN's `Object.create` page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create), you can see numerous examples of the `Object.create(Foo.prototype)` pattern in use.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `prototype` to `Error.prototype`, set `message` as the object, set `value` of object to message which should be displayed when `err.constructor` is called with `err.message` as parameter.

```js
var err = Object.create(Error.prototype, {
  message: {
    value: "error"
  },
  error: {
    value: true
  }
})

Promise.reject(err.constructor([err.message, err.error]))
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(e => console.log(e, e.message));
```